# validation for select tag using ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i want validation for email and select tag like TIN/GRN label . i am not understanding how to write validation for select and email condition using ionic2 and typescript.

this is my code,please suggest me how to write validation for email and select options.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-row class="head">
    <p>Personal Details</p>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-list class="lis1">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item width-50 >
        <ion-label floating >First Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName" maxlength="30" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item width-50  >
        <ion-label floating>Last Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lastName" maxlength="30" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-row>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"  maxlength="64" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Telephone</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="phoneNo" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>DOB</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate" required></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Preferred Payment</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="preferPay" required>
          <ion-option>NEFT / RTGS / IMPS</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Debit / Credit</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Net Banking</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Primary Category</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="category" required>
          <ion-option>Two Wheeler</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Three Wheeler</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Four Wheeler</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Sales Person Id</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="salesId"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <ion-list class="lis2"> 

    <ion-row class="com"><p>Company Details</p></ion-row>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Company Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="comName" maxlength="64" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Company Formation Day</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="comDay"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-row>
        <ion-item >
          <ion-label floating>TIN/GRN NO</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="num" required>
              <ion-option *ngFor="let nom of list" value="{{nom.value}}" checked="{{nom.checked}}" >{{nom.text}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item *ngIf="num == 1 || num == 2">
           <ion-label floating>Number</ion-label> 
           <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="num1" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Alternate Telephone</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="altTelNumber" minlength="10" maxlength="10"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Fax</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="faxNum" minlength="12" maxlength="12" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-list class="lis3">
   <ion-row class="add"><p>Address</p></ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Address1</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="add1" maxlength="64" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Address2</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="add2"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-row>

        <ion-item width-50 >
          <ion-label floating>Town/City</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="townRcity" maxlength="64"required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item width-50>
          <ion-label floating>State</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="states" required>
              <ion-option *ngFor="let item of optionsList" value="{{item.value}}" checked="{{item.checked}}">{{item.text}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row>

        <ion-item width-50>
          <ion-label floating>Country</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="countrys" required>
              <ion-option>{{country}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item width-50  >
          <ion-label floating>Pin</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="pinNum"  maxlength="6"  minlength="6" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item> 
      </ion-row>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <button primary full (click)="register()">Register</button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AutoSparesPersistence } from '../../providers/persistence/autosparesPersistence';
import {Logger} from '../../providers/logger/logger';
import {Users} from '../../providers/commerce/users';
import {Rest} from '../../providers/network/rest';
import {HomePage} from '../home/home';

/*
  Generated class for the RegistrationPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/registration/registration.html',
  providers: [Users]
})
export class RegistrationPage {
    public country;
    state: number;
  optionsList: Array<{ value: number, text: string, checked: boolean }> = [];
  num = '';
  list: Array<{ value: number, text: string, checked: boolean }> = [];

  public firstName = "";
  public lastName = "";
  public email = "";
  public phoneNo = "";
  public myDate = "";
  public preferPay = "";
  public category = "";
  public salesId = "";
  public comName = "";
  public comDay = "";
  // public num = "";
  public num1 = "";
  public altTelNumber = "";
  public faxNum = "";
  public add1 = "";
  public add2 = "";
  public townRcity = "";
  public states = "";
  public countrys = "";
  public pinNum = "";


  // public registrationForm: any;
  public registrationDetails : any;


  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private persistence: AutoSparesPersistence,
    private rest: Rest, private logger: Logger, private user:Users) {
      this.country='India';
        this.optionsList.push({ value: 1, text: 'Andhra Pradesh', checked: false });
        this.optionsList.push({ value: 2, text: 'Telangana', checked: false });
        this.optionsList.push({ value: 3, text: 'Tamilnadu', checked: false });
        this.optionsList.push({ value: 4, text: 'Karnataka', checked: false });
      this.list.push({ value: 1, text: 'TIN NO', checked: false  });
      this.list.push({ value: 2, text: 'GRN NO' , checked: false });

  }

  register() {
      var _this= this;
    this.logger.info("invoking registeration FN");

    var registrationDetails = {
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName,
      email: this.email,
      phoneNo: this.phoneNo,
      myDate: this.myDate,
      preferPay: this.preferPay,
      category: this.category,
      salesId: this.salesId,
      comName: this.comName,
      comDay: this.comDay,
      num: this.num,
      num1: this.num1,
      altTelNumber: this.altTelNumber,
      faxNum: this.faxNum,
      add1: this.add1,
      add2: this.add2,
      townRcity: this.townRcity,
      states: this.state,
      countrys: this.country,
      pinNum: this.pinNum
    }

    this.user.registerNewUser(registrationDetails, function(result,data){
      if(result  == '1'){
        var _dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
        _this.rest.setAuthToken(_dataObj.userId, _dataObj.authToken);
        _this.persistence.setLoginDetails(_dataObj.userId, _this.email, _dataObj.passwd);
        _this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
      }
      else {
        alert(data);
      }

    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear,do you want validation on submitting?Please be clearer

Comment: this is my code for registration page,when i click register button it should check  all required fileds are entered or not  and store that entire information in our database can any one help me how to write that using ionic2 and typescript